# How to make a dependent radio button based on the option selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

How do I make a dependent radio button based on the option selected?

If Engineering Projects is selected, then a radio button should appear and it must have radio buttons of abc, def, ghi, etc.

If MCA Projects is selected then a radio button should appear and it must have radio buttons of jsp, asp, php, java, etc.

If none are selected, no radio button should appear.

```
<p>
    Area Of Interest
    <select name="formGender">
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="e">Engineering Project</option>
        <option value="m">MCA Projects</option>
        <option value="t">M-Tech Projects</option>
        <option value="s">Msc Projects</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Comment: prepare all the radio buttons that are needed and hide all of them on load. on change event of select show all radio button that is connection to the selected option.

Comment: Depends on how many options and how many options those options require.  If it's lots, you could use ajax to load the dependent radios - if it's only a few, load them all up first and show/hide (much easier and better ux, but doesn't work for 100s-1000s of options or if they change dynamically over a short period of time).

Comment: Or you could use ajax and jquery to load the appropriate items when needed..

Comment: @Nikhil Alex Please implement some of the suggestions given and update the question or ask a new one.

Comment: @NikhilAlex Please mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get value of selected option and display relative radio.

```js
$("#dropdown").change(function(){
    var value = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
    $(".radioBox").hide(); 
    
    if (value == "number")
        $("#number").show();
    else if (value == "alphabet")
        $("#alphabet").show();
    else if (value == "sign")
        $("#sign").show();
});
```

```css
.radioBox {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">Select on of options</option>
    <option value="number">Number</option>
    <option value="alphabet">Alphabet</option>
    <option value="sign">Sign</option>
    <option value="none">None</option>
</select>

<div id="number" class="radioBox">
    <label>1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="number" />
    <label>2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="number" />
    <label>3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="number" />
</div>

<div id="alphabet" class="radioBox">
    <label>A</label>
    <input type="radio" name="alphabet" />
    <label>B</label>
    <input type="radio" name="alphabet" />
    <label>C</label>
    <input type="radio" name="alphabet" />
</div>

<div id="sign" class="radioBox">
    <label>@</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sign" />
    <label>#</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sign" />
    <label>$</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sign" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
$('#formGender').change(function(){
  var areaOfInterest = $('#formGender').find(":selected").text();

  if(areaOfInterest.toString() === "Engineering Project"){
    var arr=["abc","def","ghi"];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" name="sub" value="ersubs" checked>'+ arr[i]+"<br>");
    radioBtn.appendTo('#radiobuttons');
}
  }
  else{
    $( "#radiobuttons" ).empty();
  }
});
```

Add further more `if/else` as per your requirements. Here is a working [example](http://jsbin.com/tuhobu/edit?html,js,output).